# Android resource compilation failed, XML or text declaration not at start of entity

Tags: java, android, xml

The error "Android resource compilation failed" and "XML or text declaration not at start of entity."
is being shown. What do I do?

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Listview">
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: remove the <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> above <LinearLayout>

Answer (score 1):

This `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` piece should be only at the beginning.
Remove this from ConstraintLayout